# Firestore security rule get() not checking if value is correct

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to run a get() Security role but it wont trigger correctly, the Inquiry just gets blocked.

My Dababase Structure:

```
groups (collection) > groupUid (Document)
|-groupUid: 1
|-groupLeader: N0NobC2qnRdVSQ7rrpXKeYg6BtA2

groupsUsers (collection) > groupUserUid (Document)
|-authUid: 94jksJGAZihZp0jaMCmctzsEnGo1
|-groupUid: 1
|-groupUserUid: 123
```

Now i want to make a security rule, when deleting a groupsUsers Document, it should check if the signed in person who delets it has the authUid of the groups groupLeader

```js
match /groupsUsers/{itemId}{
allow read: if isSignedIn();
allow delete: if isOwner(resource.data) &&
  isSignedIn();

function isOwner(groupsUser) {
  return(
   get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupsUser.groupId)).data.groupLeader == request.auth.uid ||
   get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupsUser.groupId)).groupLeader == request.auth.uid
  )
}
}
```

i checked to just read the document and that works, so i am signed in correctly, i am signed in as N0NobC2qnRdVSQ7rrpXKeYg6BtA2 so i should be able to delete the groupsUsers doc, because groupLeader == request.auth.uid should return true, but it wont work, can anyone help?

Comment: It looks like you're querying for the group on `groupsUser.groupId`, but from your database structure it looks like the property is called `groupUid`

Comment: @grimsteel omg i am so dumb you are right thanks i did not see that the passt hours

Comment: Seems like your issue is resolved, Can you share yours solution as answer so that it helps others too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a mistake in the query, groupId should have been groupUid. Question is solved by @grimsteel